# i want to make button each time i click increase 10 px but it loop error

Tags: javascript, loops

i want to make button click each time increase 10 px but it go out loop

```
<html>
  <input type="button" id="perspectivePlus" value="perspective+10px"> 
</html>
<script>
function perspectivePlus(){
  var boxBig=document.getElementById('boxBig');
  var perspective = document.getElementById('perspective');
  for(var i =0;i<100;i+10){
    boxBig.style.width=i+"px";  
    perspective.style.perspective =i+"px";  
    return i
  }
}
var clickme=Gid('perspectivePlus').addEventListener('click',perspectivePlus);
</script>
```

Comment: Well yes, because you have a `return` statement in your loop. The `return` statement immediately exits its containing function. (Which in your case is just as well because otherwise you'd have an endless loop because you never update the value of `i`.) If your intention is for one click to simply add 10px to `boxBig`'s width then you don't need a loop at all, you need to read the current `.style.width`, add 10 to that, and then set `.style.width` to the result. If your intention is to have one click start an animation then you'll need to use `setTimeout()` rather than a loop.

Comment: @chang Rik can you add the full code? html for boxBig

Answer (score 0):

remove "return i". it is break loop.